# Index in for loop not returning last index

Tags: php

I have an image gallery and each is saved by index.. gallery1: /image here.. gallery2: / image here.. etc..
I'm using an index with multiple for loops to return the images and by column because it's either Masonry or rectangular.  I am getting the return fine except for the very last index.

```
private function rectangle($items, $columns, $contents = array()) {
    $thumbs = array('talent_thumbnail','360x207');
    $arr = array();
    $col                = round(count($items) / $columns);
    $perCol             = floor(count($items) / $columns);
    $extra              = count($items) % $columns;

    $ind = 1;
    $length = count($items);
    $arr = array();

    for($i = 0;  $i < $columns && $ind < $length; $i++) {
        $temp = array();

        for($j = 0; $j < $perCol; $j++) {
            $obj = new JObject();
            $obj->image     = $items['gallery' . $ind]['photo'];
            $obj->alt_text  = $items['gallery'. $ind]['alt_text'];
            $temp[] = $obj;
            $ind++;
        }

       if ($extra > 0) {
            $obj = new JObject();
            $obj->image     = $items['gallery'. $ind]['photo'];
            $obj->alt_text = $items['gallery'. $ind]['alt_text'];
            $temp[] = $obj;
            $ind++;
            $extra--;
        }
        $arr[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

I know it can't be that hard but I'm not that good at it right yet.
Any help is so much welcome.
Thank You.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do and the code is not clear but your ind is 1 based index and arrays are 0 based index change $ind < $length to $ind < $length +1 it may work

Comment: The function has no return, is the array `$arr` supposed to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the variable `$ind` to 1, count the length of the array, and then initialize the for loop with the condition `$ind < $length`.
When `$ind` reaches the index needed to access the last item, the loop is not run again, since `$ind` is now equal to `$length`, not smaller.

You can fix this by changing the condition in your for-loop to "less or equal":

`$i < $columns && $ind <= $length`
This runs the loop once more when `$ind` has reached the last index.

Comment: This is what I needed.  The reason I set the Index to 1 is that it would look for 0 and my galleries are indexed beginning with 1..2.. 3.  Works fine and was simple.

Comment: If this solved your question, please also mark this answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably the problem is at this line:

```
$ind = 1;
```

In PHP non-associative arrays have the indexes starting to `0` instead of `1`:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
print_r($arr);

// output:
 Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )
```

So, try to change that line in your code to:

```
$ind = 0;
```

Complete code:

```
private function rectangle($items, $columns, $contents = array()) {
    $thumbs = array('talent_thumbnail','360x207');
    $arr = array();
    $col                = round(count($items) / $columns);
    $perCol             = floor(count($items) / $columns);
    $extra              = count($items) % $columns;

    $ind = 0;
    $length = count($items);
    $arr = array();

    for($i = 0;  $i < $columns && $ind < $length; $i++) {
        $temp = array();

        for($j = 0; $j < $perCol; $j++) {
            $obj = new JObject();
            $obj->image     = $items['gallery' . $ind]['photo'];
            $obj->alt_text  = $items['gallery'. $ind]['alt_text'];
            $temp[] = $obj;
            $ind++;
        }

       if ($extra > 0) {
            $obj = new JObject();
            $obj->image     = $items['gallery'. $ind]['photo'];
            $obj->alt_text = $items['gallery'. $ind]['alt_text'];
            $temp[] = $obj;
            $ind++;
            $extra--;
        }
        $arr[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, in this case it's a keyed array where the keys have the pattern `"gallery{number}"`. In addition the problem according to the description is not that the first item is skipped, but the last item is.